# Using button in a panel class to call ActionListener in the frame class

Tags: java, swing, class, actionlistener

I started codig Java last weekend and I've read most of the basic stuff. I'm trying to separate my frame from main method, and panels from the frame so they are all in separate class files. I have trouble calling ActionLister in "Frame1" class with a button (buttonBack) in the "TheGame" class. The button should trigger the Listener which in turn should remove theGame panel and add mainMenu panel to frame1. I know that CardLayout is better suited for swapping panels but i want to learn the limits and workarounds before i go do it the "easy" way, i feel that you learn much more that way.

Here is some of my code:

Main:

```
public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args){

    Frame1 frame1 = new Frame1();
    frame1.frame1();

    }
}
```

Frame1:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


class Frame1 {

private JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Name");

public void frame1() {

    TheGame theGame = new TheGame();
    MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();

// Frame options
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);


// Creating a top menu
    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    frame1.setJMenuBar(menubar);

    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    menubar.add(file);

    JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
    menubar.add(help);

    JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    file.add(exit);

    JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");
    help.add(about);


// Creating action for the menuitem "exit".
class exitaction implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
exit.addActionListener(new exitaction());


// Creating listener for the menuitem "about".
    class aboutaction implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            JDialog dialogabout = new JDialog();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialogabout, "Made by: ");
        }
    }
    about.addActionListener(new aboutaction());


// Add the panels, pack and setVisible
    theGame.theGame();
    mainMenu.mainMenu();
    frame1.add(theGame.getGUI());


// This is the ActionListener i have trouble connecting with the buttonBack in the "theGame" class
    class Action implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            frame1.remove(theGame.getGUI());
            frame1.add(MainMenu.getGUI());
        }
    }

    frame1.pack();
    frame1.setVisible(true);



    }

    public JFrame getGUI() {
        return frame1;
    }



}
```

MainMenu:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class MainMenu {

private JPanel mainMenu = new JPanel (new GridBagLayout());

public void mainMenu() {

// Using the GridBagLayout therefore creating the constraints "grid"
    GridBagConstraints grid = new GridBagConstraints();

// Adjusting grid insets
    grid.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);


// Creating Label
    JLabel introduction = new JLabel("Name");
    grid.gridx = 1;
    grid.gridy = 3;
    mainMenu.add(introduction, grid);


// Creating buttons Start Game, Highscore and Exit Game
    JButton buttonNewGame = new JButton("New Game");
    buttonNewGame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
    grid.gridx = 1;
    grid.gridy = 5;
    mainMenu.add(buttonNewGame, grid);

    JButton buttonHighscore = new JButton("Highscore");
    buttonHighscore.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
    grid.gridx = 1;
    grid.gridy = 6;
    mainMenu.add(buttonHighscore, grid);

    JButton buttonExit = new JButton("Exit Game");
    buttonExit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 50));
    grid.gridx = 1;
    grid.gridy = 7;
    mainMenu.add(buttonExit, grid);


    }


    public JComponent getGUI() {
        return mainMenu;
    }
}
```

TheGame:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


class TheGame {

private JPanel theGame = new JPanel (new GridBagLayout());

public void  theGame() {

// Using the GridBagLayout therefore creating the constraints "grid"
    GridBagConstraints grid = new GridBagConstraints();

// Adjusting grid insets
    grid.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

// Creating a label
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Press the BACK button to go back to Main Menu");
    label1.setVisible(true);
    grid.gridx = 1;
    grid.gridy = 0;
    theGame.add(label1,grid);

// Creating BACK button
    JButton buttonBack = new JButton("BACK");
    buttonBack.setVisible(true);
    grid.gridx = 1;
    grid.gridy = 1;
    buttonBack.addActionListener(new --); // This is the button i want to connect with the ActionListener on Frame1 class
    theGame.add(buttonBack, grid);

    }


    public JComponent getGUI() {
        return theGame;
    }


}
```

I've tried moving the ActionListener outside of methods, inside the Main, declaring it static, but haven't been able to call it anyways. I've also looked at other posts like this: [Add an actionListener to a JButton from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104014/add-an-actionlistener-to-a-jbutton-from-another-class) but have not been able to implement it in to my code.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer -- use MVC (model-view-controller) structure (and CardLayout) for the swapping of your views. If you don't want to do that, then your listener should have a reference to the container that does the swapping, and so that the listener can notify this container that a swap should occur. The container will then call its own code to do the swapping. To do this you need to pass references around including a reference to the main GUI to wherever it is needed. This can get messy, which is why MVC, which is more work, is usually better -- fewer connections/complexity in the long term.

Side note -- don't pass a JDialog into a JOptionPane as a JOptionPane **is** a specialized JDialog, and you shouldn't have a top level window displaying a top level window. Instead pass in a JPanel.

For example:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PassRef {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MyMain mainPanel = new MyMain();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pass Reference");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyMain extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 600;
    private static final int PREF_H = 450;
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private MenuView menuView = new MenuView(this);
    private ActionView1 actionView1 = new ActionView1(this);

    public MyMain() {
        setLayout(cardLayout);
        add(menuView, MenuView.NAME);
        add(actionView1, ActionView1.NAME);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        } else {
            return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
        }
    }

    public void showCard(String key) {
        cardLayout.show(this, key);
        // or swap by hand if you don't want to use CardLayout
        // but remember to revalidate and repaint whenever doing it by hand
    }
}

class MenuView extends JPanel {
    public static final String NAME = "Menu View";

    public MenuView(MyMain myMain) {
        setName(NAME);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Menu"));
        add(new JButton(new GoToAction("Action 1", ActionView1.NAME, myMain)));
    }

}

class ActionView1 extends JPanel {
    public static final String NAME = "Action View 1";

    public ActionView1(MyMain myMain) {
        setName(NAME);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(NAME));
        add(new JButton(new GoToAction("Main Menu", MenuView.NAME, myMain)));
    }

}

class GoToAction extends AbstractAction {
    private String key;
    private MyMain myMain;

    public GoToAction(String name, String key, MyMain myMain) {
        super(name);
        this.key = key;
        this.myMain = myMain;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        myMain.showCard(key);
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like it's too early for me to use MVC, i just started coding and this "quiz" game is just a way for me to use the stuff i think i learned, to see what i have to read more on, and for now, the only thing i cannot implement in my code (when separating classes) is ActionListener. I would appreciate it if you would show/tell me how i would get from for example the MainMenu to TheGame by clicking on the button buttonNewGame. It should be as simple as buttonNewGame.addActionListener("ref") and then on the Frame1  make a listener (class "ref" implements ...) to add/remove the desired panels.

Comment: @Codex: I pretty much show you how to do it all here in running code -- just borrow the concepts as the concepts will work in your framework. Please let me know if anything in my example above is confusing. As a caveat though -- always try to borrow concepts but write your own code. Things work much better this way.

Comment: @Codex *"I feel like it's too early for me to use MVC"* - It's never too early to do those things which will help solve your current problem and many of the problems you might have in the future

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That is exactly what i wanted to do and it was possible for me to do that with my code too when it was all in one file, i just read that it would be smart to keep the panels in separate files to make it easier to work with in the future and that's where the problem arose, i could not get the ActionListener in my frame to add/remove the panels.

Would i be able to put the ActionView1 and MenuView classes in separate files and make the buttons go back and forth? If so, how?

And sorry for the late response, i was not at home.

Comment: @Codex: experiment, try, and then get back to me and see how it works out.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Wow after an hour of trying to reference to MenuView that i copied to a separate file, I figure out that i don't need to. But why? Does Java run all the files in the project when i run the main file? Even though they aren't referred to in the main?